# Ruby pattern matching and printing the wrong line

Tags: ruby, parsing

I am new to Ruby and working on how to read text files and check if the pattern matches or not. I am not not sure how to print the wrong lines.

For example, this is the text file:

```
id: 1   food: apple, banana
id: 2   food: orange
ids: 3   food: apple, banana
id: 4   food: hello, yellow
id: 5food: apple, banana
```

Reading the file

```
File.open(ARGV[0]) do |f1|  
while line = f1.gets  
pattern = /id[:] [[:digit:]]+ food[:] [a-z,]+/
puts line.scan(pattern)
end
```

This prints the following results

```
id: 1   food: apple, banana
id: 2   food: orange
id: 4   food: hello, yellow
```

But I want to print the wrong lines

```
ids: 3   food: apple, banana
id: 5food: apple, banana
```

I am not sure how do check if the pattern doesn't match then print the lines that are formatted incorrectly.

Comment: I feel like there's a gaping hole in my Ruby education. What is `synset`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the previous answer had `/\A...\z/` to properly anchor this test. Right now you've removed those and this will match `xid: ...` because the middle is fine.

Comment: I don't understand your regex, `pattern = /id[:] [[:digit:]]+ synset[:] [a-z,]+/`. Firstly, I've never heard of "`synset`" in the context of a Ruby regex. Could you supply the doc? Also, there's no need to put each colon in a character class, only a single space is permitted after "`id:`", and `[a-z,]+` matches many strings it shouldn't, such as "`,,,,,`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scan` returns an empty array if there are no matches. So you could do

```
File.open(ARGV[0]) do |f1|  
  while line = f1.gets  
    pattern = /id[:] [[:digit:]]+ synset[:] [a-z,]+/
    puts line if line.scan(pattern).empty?
  end
end
```

Another way, cleaner. You can use `=~` method to see if a line match a pattern. And it returns the matching index if the pattern match or nil, if none matches.

```
File.open(ARGV[0]) do |f1|  
  while line = f1.gets  
    pattern = /id[:] [[:digit:]]+ synset[:] [a-z,]+/
    puts line unless line =~ pattern
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the file is read into the variable `contents`:

```
contents =<<_
id: 1   food: apple, banana
id: 2   food: orange
ids: 3   food: apple, banana
id: 4   food: hello, yellow
id: 5food: apple, banana
_
```

If `food:` is required, you could use the following regular expression.

```
r = /
    \A                   # match beginning of string
    id:\s+               # match "id:" followed by > 0 spaces
    \d+\s+               # match > 0 digits followed by > 0 spaces
    food:\s+             # match "food:" followed by > 0 spaces
    [[:alpha:]]+         # match > 0 (uppercase or lowercase) letters  
    (?:,\s+[[:alpha:]]+) # match a comma, > 0 spaces, > 0 letters in a non-capture group
    *                    # match > 0 instances of the aforementioned non-capture group
    \n                   # match newline      
    \z                   # match end of string
    /x                   # free-spacing regex definition mode

contents.each_line { |line| puts line if line !~ r }
```

prints

```
ids: 3   food: apple, banana
id: 5food: apple, banana
```